# How can I prove that $\inf B=\sup A$?

Tags: real-numbers

> Let $B$ be the set of all the upper bounds of the non-empty bounded subset $A\subseteq\Bbb R$. Prove that $\inf B=\sup A$.

I divided it into two areas ($\inf B>\sup A$, $\inf B<\sup A$) and tried to show a contradiction. Is it the right approach? How can I prove it?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Consider the _definition_ of the supremum. How does it relate to all of the other upper bounds of a set?

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Please search the site before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

The following is what we can say:

- $\sup A\leq b\;\forall\;b\in B\quad$ (Why?)
- Also by definition, $\inf B\leq b\;\forall\;b\in B$. In particular $\sup A\in B$.

Can you complete?